# Join tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerpivot

I have table A that contains lots of data, and it looks like this

| Product | Date | Sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| nameA | 01.01.2022. | 120 |
| nameB | 01.01.2022. | 300 |
| nameA | 02.01.2022. | 110 |
| nameB | 02.01.2022. | 310 |

I also have many other tables for every date, for example table "01.01.2022." contains data for nameA and nameB only for that date. Then table "02.01.2022." also contains data for nameA and nameB but for 02.01.2022. Table "01.01.2022" looks like this:

| Product | Date | Planned_sale |
| --- | --- | --- |
| nameA | 01.01.2022. | 110 |
| nameB | 01.01.2022. | 295 |

All other "date" tables look the same, just with different data. Data in every Product column is the same (names are always the same, but there might be tables without nameA product for example).

I need to join table A with all other tables ("01.01.2022.", "02.01.2022." and so on (I have this for first quarter)) and get something like this for Power Pivot

| Product | 01-01-2022. Planned | 01.01.2022 Sold | 02.01.20022 Planned | 02.01.20022 Sold | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NameA | 110 | 120 | 100 | 110 | ... |
| NameB | 295 | 300 | 280 | 290 | ... |

There should be column for every day of the quarter and this means I need to join every table for this date with "A" table. I know that this is really bad normalization, but this data is imported from excel in temp database and it is what it is.

Is it even possible to achieve this with these bad tables? It's for Power Pivot report if that helps.

Comment: "this data is imported from excel in temp database": regardless of the source of the data, what's stopping you restructuring it, so you can easily query it?

Comment: I'm with @HoneyBadger - when importing you should be appending to a single table that has the three columns you need then import all of the files into the same table. As you mention PowerPivot then why not use Power Query to merge all of the spreadsheets before loading?

Comment: So your plan is to join 90+ tables, I hope you don't care about performance

Comment: I have no idea how power query works, this job is usually done by someone else, but now I have to. I don't know a lot about excel, or power pivot or power query. If you could help me do this through Excel it would be also nice, I just need to finish this soon.

Comment: *"this job is usually done by someone else"* So talk to that person to get some understanding of what they do. Or review their process documentation and follow the steps; if you get stuck then again talk to them or post a question explicitly about the point at which you are confused.

Comment: You should merge all this data into one table, then it will be far easier to query

Answer (score 1):

This really isn't a way to use a relational database but, assuming you are stuck with this and just want to get something done, here is one way you could do it (assuming SQL Server 2017 or better). First, assuming these tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.A
(
  Product varchar(32), 
  Date date, 
  Sold int
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.[01.01.2022]
(
  Product varchar(32), Date date, Planned_sale int
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.[02.01.2022]
(
  Product varchar(32), Date date, Planned_sale int
);

...
```

And this sample data:

```
INSERT dbo.A(Product, Date, Sold) VALUES
('nameA', '20220101', 120),
('nameB', '20220101', 300),
('nameA', '20220102', 110),
('nameB', '20220102', 310);

INSERT dbo.[01.01.2022] VALUES
('nameA', '20220101', 110),
('nameB', '20220101', 295);

INSERT dbo.[02.01.2022] VALUES
('nameA', '20220102', 100),
('nameB', '20220102', 280);
```

This query will get what you need:

```
;WITH src AS
(
            SELECT Product, Date, Planned_sale FROM [01.01.2022] 
  UNION ALL SELECT Product, Date, Planned_sale FROM [02.01.2022] 
),
next AS
(
  SELECT A.Sold, A.Product, src.Date, src.Planned_sale
  FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN src 
    ON A.Product = src.Product
    AND A.Date = src.Date
)
SELECT 
  Product, 
  [01.01.2022 Planned] = MAX(CASE WHEN Date = '20220101' THEN Planned_sale END),
  [01.01.2022 Sold]    = MAX(CASE WHEN Date = '20220101' THEN Sold END),
  [02.01.2022 Planned] = MAX(CASE WHEN Date = '20220102' THEN Planned_sale END),
  [02.01.2022 Sold]    = MAX(CASE WHEN Date = '20220102' THEN Sold END)
FROM next GROUP BY Product;
```

Output:

| Product | 01.01.2022 Planned | 01.01.2022 Sold | 02.01.2022 Planned | 02.01.2022 Sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| nameA | 110 | 120 | 100 | 110 |
| nameB | 295 | 300 | 280 | 310 |

But you don't want to have to hard-code all of those dates into your query every day (or however often you run this). So you can use dynamic SQL. This produces something quite close (except for identical formatting):

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'',  
     @Unions nvarchar(max) = N'',
     @Output nvarchar(max) = N'',
     @crlf   nvarchar(2)   = char(13) + char(10);
     
DECLARE @csep nvarchar(20) = N',' + @crlf + space(2),
        @usep nvarchar(20) = @crlf + N' UNION ALL ' + @crlf;
        
SELECT @Unions = STRING_AGG
            (N'  SELECT Product, Date, Planned_sale FROM ' 
              + QUOTENAME(name), @usep),
  @Output = STRING_AGG
            (CONCAT(QUOTENAME(name + ' Planned'),
             N' = MAX(CASE WHEN Date = ', char(39), 
              CONVERT(char(8), CONVERT(datetime, name, 104), 112),
              char(39), N' THEN Planned_sale END),', @crlf,
              QUOTENAME(name + ' Sold'),
             N' = MAX(CASE WHEN Date = ', char(39), 
              CONVERT(char(8), CONVERT(datetime, name, 104), 112),
              char(39), N' THEN Sold END)'), @csep)
FROM sys.tables 
 WHERE name LIKE N'[0-1][0-9].[0-3][0-9].20[0-9][0-9]';
-- for 2022, use N'[0-1][0-9].[0-3][0-9].2022';

SET @sql = CONCAT_WS(@crlf, N';WITH src AS (', @Unions, '), next AS (
  SELECT A.Sold, A.Product, src.Date, src.Planned_sale
  FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN src 
    ON A.Product = src.Product
    AND A.Date = src.Date)
SELECT Product, ', @Output, N'
  FROM next GROUP BY Product;');
 
 SELECT @sql;
 --EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Output:

```
;WITH src AS (
  SELECT Product, Date, Planned_sale FROM [01.01.2022]
 UNION ALL 
  SELECT Product, Date, Planned_sale FROM [02.01.2022]
), next AS (
  SELECT A.Sold, A.Product, src.Date, src.Planned_sale
  FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN src 
    ON A.Product = src.Product
    AND A.Date = src.Date)
SELECT Product, 
[01.01.2022 Planned] = MAX(CASE WHEN Date = '20220101' THEN Planned_sale END),
[01.01.2022 Sold] = MAX(CASE WHEN Date = '20220101' THEN Sold END),
  [02.01.2022 Planned] = MAX(CASE WHEN Date = '20220102' THEN Planned_sale END),
[02.01.2022 Sold] = MAX(CASE WHEN Date = '20220102' THEN Sold END)

  FROM next GROUP BY Product;
```

Formatting is slightly off because perfecting it is tedious, but when you uncomment the `EXEC` line, it produces the same results as the first query.

Here's a working example that also creates a 3rd table with only one of the products:

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=66fefc1d775116f9fa92749e3df5409d)

If you are < 2017 there are certainly ways to do this without `STRING_AGG()` and `CONCAT_WS()`, but they're going to be more painful.